# Adding a button to php

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

```
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
      $output .= '
       <tr>
        <td>'.$row["reon"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["broj_na_tezga"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["ime"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["prezime"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["rok_na_dogovor"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["duledzija"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["rez_pau"].'</td>
         //i want to add these buttons but i keep getting an error
        <td>'<a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Промени</a>
      <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Избриши</a>
      </td>

      '; } echo $output; } else { echo 'Корисникот не постои'; } ?>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

im new to this and im trying to add buttons but i get an error to be exact" Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'href' (T_STRING)" pls help. tnx

Comment: try change `href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>"` to `href="/delete.php?id=".$row['id']."?"`

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
echo "<td><a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Download</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is messed up. This should work:

```
<?php

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
      $output .= '
       <tr>
        <td>'.$row["reon"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["broj_na_tezga"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["ime"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["prezime"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["rok_na_dogovor"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["duledzija"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["rez_pau"].'</td>
         //i want to add these buttons but i keep getting an error
        <td><a href="update.php?id='.$row['id'].'" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Промени</a>
      <a href="delete.php?id='.$row['id'].'" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Избриши</a>
      </td>

      '; } 
      echo $output; } else { echo 'Корисникот не постои'; } ?>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: Thank you sir for the help. Still learning and will try to improve.

Comment: No Problem. Accept my answer if it worked for you.